# How to send headers while sending SMS in twilio and receive the when user reply back to the message

Tags: c#, twilio

How to send headers while sending SMS in twilio and receive the response when user reply back to the message, I am using the below code but when i reply back it is not giving the header details

```cs
// Create the Twilio client
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

// Create the HTTP client
var client = new HttpClient();

// Create the HTTP request
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Post,
    "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{accountid}/Messages"
);

// Set the authorization header
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{accountSid}:{authToken}"))
);

// Add the message parameters
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "Body", "Hello, world!" },
    { "From", "+1 507 708 7284" }, // Your Twilio phone number
    { "To", "+14243089011" } // The recipient's phone number
};

// Add the X-Twilio-Additional-Metadata header
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
request.Content.Headers.Add("X-Twilio-Additional-Metadata", "test");

// Send the request and get the response
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do this. I'd recommend storing your metadata somewhere else like in a database and associate it to the phone number you're sending towards. When you receive a message, retrieve the associated metadata from the database.